# How to write Switch Statement in angularJS Controller

Tags: angularjs, switch-statement

How to write Switch Statement in angularJS Controller ?

My Source Code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td><a href="" ng-click="SwitchFuction(x.Name, x.Sno)">{{ x.Country }}</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.names = [
        { Sno: '1', Name: 'Jani', Country: 'Norway' },
        { Sno: '2', Name: 'Hege', Country: 'Sweden' },
        { Sno: '3', Name: 'Kai', Country: 'Denmark' }
    ];

    $scope.SuperFunction = function (id) {
        alert(id);
    };

    $scope.SwitchFuction = function (name, sno) {
        switch (sno) {
            case '1'
                alert("1. Selected Name: " + name );
                break;
            case '2'
                alert("2. Selected Name: " + name );
                break;
            default:

        }
    };

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How to Write the Switch Statement within the function **SwitchFuction** ???
In the above Source Code contains some semantic error. Kindly assist how to write the Switch Statement?

The Error Screen :

[image: FireFox Screen Shot]

Comment: Can you provide plunker?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

there is a syntax error in your `SwitchFunction` after each case `:` is missing
 correct code:

```
$scope.SwitchFuction = function (id, caseStr) {
        switch (caseStr) {
            case '1':
                alert("Selected Case Number is 1");
                break;
            case '2':
                alert("Selected Case Number is 2");
                break;
            default:

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

AngularJS is built on top of JavaScript and it has no different syntax for switch case than JavaScript(As long as you are using it in script). JavaScript support switch case statements with following syntax.

```
switch (expression) {
  case value1:
    //Statements executed when the result of expression matches value1
    [break;]
  case value2:
    //Statements executed when the result of expression matches value2
    [break;]
  ...
  case valueN:
    //Statements executed when the result of expression matches valueN
    [break;]
  default:
    //Statements executed when none of the values match the value of the expression
    [break;]
}
```

[**Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: Ok. Then whats wrong in my above script? Kindly assist my Script to make bug free...

Comment: I attached the Screen Shot. Kindly refer it.

Comment: Without Switch Statement it works fine and it shows the List otherwise it shows the Screen as like the Screenshot.

Comment: Screenshot is not proper

Comment: The output of the above Source Code is 

{{ x.Name }}  {{ x.Country }}

Comment: Enclose **<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>** inside head tag.

Answer (score 3):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
        <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
        <td><a href="" ng-click=SwitchFuction(x.Name,$index)>{{ x.Country }}</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope) {

      $scope.names = [{
        Name: 'Jani',
        Country: 'Norway'
      }, {
        Name: 'Hege',
        Country: 'Sweden'
      }, {
        Name: 'Kai',
        Country: 'Denmark'
      }];

      $scope.SuperFunction = function(id) {
        alert(id);
      };

      $scope.SwitchFuction = function(id, caseStr) {
        switch (caseStr) {
          case 0:
            alert("Selected Case Number is 0");
            break;
          case 1:
            alert("Selected Case Number is 1");
            break;
          default:
            alert("Selected Case Number is other than 0 and 1");
            break;

        }
      };

    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/15I8mU9BPqvJBMKiNV4G?p=preview)

Comment: above is the syntax corrected code of the asked question. Here the java script switch and argument passing are discussed. read more about $index  at   :             [here](https://thinkster.io/egghead/index-event-log)