# How to use Switch Statement in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, switch-statement

I built an app.js in my cordova application. There is speech recognition in this module, as $scope.recog. In this function I want to catch a word using **Switch Statement**, and this is my code:

```
$scope.recog = function() {
    var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    var result = event.results[0][0].transcript;
    $scope.SwitchFuction = function (result){
        switch(result){
        case 'login':
        $scope.loginFn();
            break;
        case 'sign up':
        $location.path('/register');
            break;
        case 'register':
        $scope.registerFn();
            break;
        case 'cancel':
        $scope.cancelregisterFn();
            break;
        case 'go to home':
        $location.path('/home');
            break;
        case 'go to add friend':
        $location.path('/addfriend');
            break;
        case 'go to friend request':
        $location.path('/friendrequest');
            break;
        case 'go to pending request':
        $location.path('/penddingrequest');
            break;
        case 'add':
        $scope.addfriends();
            break;
        case 'log out':
        $scope.logout();
            break;
        }
    };
    $scope.$apply()
    };
    recognition.start();
  };
```

The recognition is working, but the switch statement isn't working Am I wrong to write it or is there something I am missing? Thanks for your help

Comment: Where are you calling `$scope.SwitchFunction(result);`?

Comment: its my bad, sorry, I should not use that function, thanks

Comment: I recommend you to use `ui-route` for routing and not a switch case. You can read documentation about `ui-route`here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your switch function is inside another function which you aren't calling. If you want to use then you'll need to call it

Comment: Or remove the `SwitchFunction()` and run the switch case procedurally.

Comment: thats my bad, when I look up to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131341/how-to-write-switch-statement-in-angularjs-controller I though I must make that function too, Thanks for your help, I will delete that function

Answer (score 0):

You did not call SwitchFunction correctly. This may help you.

```
$scope.SwitchFuction = function (result){
  switch(result){
    case 'login':
        $scope.loginFn();
        break;
    case 'sign up':
        $location.path('/register');
        break;
    case 'register':
        $scope.registerFn();
        break;
    case 'cancel':
        $scope.cancelregisterFn();
        break;
    case 'go to home':
        $location.path('/home');
        break;
    case 'go to add friend':
        $location.path('/addfriend');
        break;
    case 'go to friend request':
        $location.path('/friendrequest');
        break;
    case 'go to pending request':
        $location.path('/penddingrequest');
        break;
    case 'add':
        $scope.addfriends();
        break;
    case 'log out':
        $scope.logout();
        break;
}
$scope.recog = function() {
   var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
   recognition.onresult = function(event) {
   var result = event.results[0][0].transcript;
   $scope.SwitchFuction(result);
   $scope.$apply();
};

recognition.start();
```

Comment: Correct, which has already been established. Please update your answer for the OP and any future user.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I just delete my SwitchFunction(), and use Switch directly in recog(). Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the use of `ui-route`for routing in Angular.

But, other hand, if you want to solve the bug of the `switch-case` try this:

```
  function switchFunction (result) {
      switch(result){
        case 'login':
          $scope.loginFn();
          break;
        case 'sign up':
          $location.path('/register');
          break;
        case 'register':
          $scope.registerFn();
          break;
        case 'cancel':
          $scope.cancelregisterFn();
          break;
        case 'go to home':
          $location.path('/home');
          break;
        case 'go to add friend':
          $location.path('/addfriend');
          break;
        case 'go to friend request':
          $location.path('/friendrequest');
          break;
        case 'go to pending request':
          $location.path('/penddingrequest');
          break;
        case 'add':
          $scope.addfriends();
          break;
        case 'log out':
          $scope.logout();
          break;
      }
    }

    function onResult (event) {
      var result = event.results[0][0].transcript;
      switchFunction(result); //YOU FORGET THIS CALL
    }

    function recog () {
      var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
      recognition.onresult = onResult;
      recognition.start();
      $scope.$apply()
    }

    $scope.recog = recog;
    $scope.switchFunction = switchFunction;
```